# High memory usage and poor speed on CAD software in Win10, best strategy to investigate?

Tags: memory, performance, cad

I have a Dell XPS15 7590 with 8Gb of RAM and recently very poor CAD design performances.
I think it's due to RAM usage, since it is always around 90% of usage even with just Netflix open for example.
Now I don't really know how to investigate this problem, can you suggest me which data should I look at? I don't see any particular process with a lot of used ram tbh
Thank you very much

Comment: Where we have customers using CAD software, the machine is an i7 processor with 16GB of memory, possibly more depending on the machine and Netflix is not running at the same time.

Comment: You could try launching the Windows in Secure mode, and then start the CAD software. Then every other program that wants resources should be disabled, and you can see what the CAD program really uses. It depends on the CAD program, I have 32Gb of RAM, which is way too much for the smaller CAD programs, but there are other programs I cannot use because there is not enough RAM. But usually you should be ok with 8Gb, although 16 or more are better for more fluent execution of the commands. But I would say that the problem is probably the CPU or the GPU.

Comment: @DarkDiamond I have to specify it's not anything heavy and it used to run much more smoothly before this RAM thing happened.

Comment: @John can't afford anything better honestly, and there's a RAM problem quite clearly. I meant only Netflix, not Netflix+CAD

Comment: You can try running diagnostics on the RAM. Maybe there is a fault in the RAM bar, which could block it from working smoothly. There is a RAM diagnostics tool from Dell, and one from Windows itself. Both can be launched from within Bios/Uefi. Dependent on the manufacturer of your RAM, if it is broken, there is no other option than to replace it.